# Unresolved tag in PyCharm

Tags: django, tags, pycharm, templatetags

I have this issue of pycharm showing me unresolved tag after i successfully loaded the file containing the custom tag. Please someone help!!

[image: image showing pycharm displaying the warning]

this is the content of my carton-tags.py file containing custom template tags

```
from django import template

from carton.cart import Cart
from carton.settings import CART_TEMPLATE_TAG_NAME


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_cart(context, session_key=None, cart_class=Cart):
    """
    Make the cart object available in template.

    Sample usage::

        {% load carton_tags %}
        {% get_cart as cart %}
        {% for product in cart.products %}
            {{ product }}
        {% endfor %}
    """
    request = context['request']
    return cart_class(request.session, session_key=session_key)

register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True, name=CART_TEMPLATE_TAG_NAME)(get_cart)
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Is the issue just in PyCharm or does it throw an exception?

Comment: it doesn't throw any exception. However, the tag doesn't perform its duty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `get_cart` filter as a template tag in you template. This is why pycharm is showing errors.

```
@register.filter
def get_cart(context, session_key=None, cart_class=Cart):
```

You should remove `register.filter` decorator if you are not using it as a filter.